# Counter / Analytics in SpringXD

Tags: java, spring, bigdata

I'm trying to get familiar with SpringXD via the [Getting Started Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-xd/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#taps) but I can't seem to get a simple counter working.

I've got a simple `http` source setup and I just want to count messages going by, but no matter what I do I end up in an infinite loop and cause a stack overflow

The steps to reproduce:

```
# Start the installed redis-server in it's own tab
./redis/bin/redis-server

# start the single node in it's own tab
./xd/bin/xd-singlenode 


# open a new tab for executing the following
curl -d "http --port=9020 | file" http://localhost:8080/streams/httptest
curl -d "Hello basic" http://localhost:9020

# try a counterr
curl -d "tap@httptest | counter --name=postCount" http://localhost:8080/streams/httptest
curl -d "Hello count 1" http://localhost:9020 # begin infinite loop...
curl -d "Hello count 2" http://localhost:9020 # never make it here
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a tap actually creates a second stream, so you need to post to a different URL (you're currently posting to the same `http://localhost:8080/streams/httptest`, which is the cause of the infinite loop I guess)

Future versions will have better reporting when trying to create a stream with a name already taken. I created https://jira.springsource.org/browse/XD-299 to track it

Also, note that when running in singlenode mode, you don't need the redis server.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to make sense on the second stream issue; I'll check this out tomorrow. From what I remember, I did have to get Redis running for the taps to work, even in singlenode, but I'll check that also

Comment: Yes, you are correct regarding redis for analytics (as of M1 at least), sorry for the misleading comment.